# CAN-SPAM and transactional emails without legitimate physical address (for foreign webmaster)

Tags: email, spam, authentication, users, accounts

**Situation**

I am a very small time web developer working on a personal web project. This website will be sending only two types of emails, a email validation email and a forgot password email.

I do not want all emails my website sends out having my personal home address for privacy reasons, but realise this is required under the CAN-SPAM act. I am on a very small budget so can not buy a Post Office Box.

More about the situation

- There will be an unsubscribe link that will prevent any emails to that email address in the future
- I do not live in the US
- I will be emailing visitors when setting up accounts / resetting passwords
- The emails will have no advertisements. The reset password/verify email address pages on the site will not have advertisements but other pages on the website will have one or so.
- I do not consider myself to be doing anything black-hat / grey-hat.

As I am not in the US, there are no financial penalties that would affect me, but I do not want the site to be affected. I am not even sure if the CAN-SPAM would be applicable as the emails are more transactional messages than commercial messages.

**Question**

Does anyone know if there will be any serious repercussions for not having a legitimate physical address on these common email types? Or can anyone recommend a work-around for not having one?

**My guesses from research so far**

Possible repercussions from not having physical address on emails:

- Much greater chance on being auto-classified as SPAM?
- Potential backlash or dislike from group of users who think a physical address looks more professional?
- Potential legal action against web host, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Can-Spam Act, Yes you need to specify Physical address in every email.

**Possible Impacts:**

Emails being delivered to spam box: Less likely.
Dislike from User : Not mostly but for few.
Legal action: This can be defended as these are only verification emails.

**Suggestion:**

What I suggest is a few pixels wide footer with address written on it. If you want to hide it use Same font color as your footer.

This might not be an extraordinary solution. But this is what can be done.